# Format value in legend in dygraph plot in R

Tags: r, dygraphs

I'm using the excellent dygraphs R package. One thing that I don't seem to find in the documentation is the possibility of passing a formatting function to `dyLegend` in the same way it's possible for `dyAxis` (e.g. `valueAxisFormatter`). The legend defaults to scientific notation for values in the millions, which most of my audience does not like.

Does anyone know of a way to pass a JS formatting function?

Thank you.

Comment: Solved my own question: the ```valueFormatter``` parameter ```dyAxis``` controls this option.

Comment: You should actually post your answer for this not a random comment.